# Data entered in index.php cannot show on process.php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, xampp

Was trying to follow a tuitorial online on how to submit data using html to mysql database.

I created 2 php files named index.php and process.php. What i wanted to show was what I typed in inside index.php will show on process.php when I clicked on the button "add employee". But nothing showed up.

Here is what's inside index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>


<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" />
<br />
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" />
<br />
<label>Department</label>
<input type="text" name="department" />
<br />
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" />

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a Screenshot of the form.
[click here for index.php image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqdYO.jpg)

Wile here is what's inside the process.php

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
```

This is what shows up
[process.php image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap0MA.png)

Sorry a beginner at this. Hope you guys can help. Thank you!

Comment: First specify the form action attribute to the page where you want to display the output <form method="post" action="process.php"> and after that you have to display the data like **$_POST['first_name']** in the process.php page. if so not working you better keep a name for the submit button and call in the process.php page like this. if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $_POST['first_name']; } provided the submit button name is **submit** or any name you keep. That is the thing you will find the Output.

Comment: Have you got your error rectified @Jas Soloria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the "action"?

```
<form method="post" action="/process.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what you need.Somethings like this:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST['first_name']);
```

Or use `foreach` loop to get full array value.

You can go through with fill up `action` tag so when you `submit` the form it will go to `proccess.php` page.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
```